# What's the lifecycle of multiple Android Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, dependencies, lifecycle

The lifecycle of a *single Android [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)* is [pretty clearly defined](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle).

However what if you have **multiple Fragments**: Will `onViewCreated()` be called for all fragments (in random order) and **only then** `onActivityCreated()` for all fragments (in random order)? i.e., When one fragment `onActivityCreated()` is called can we assume `onViewCreated()` was called for all fragments?

More generally, are there events that can happen in various order for various instances of Fragment?

The reason I'm asking is mostly for a specific case where I'd like to have two Fragments to talk to one another (*one depends on the other*) and until more refactoring is done I've no better solution.

#### EDIT

I'm interested only in the case of fragments **restored by the Android framework** on Activity recreate (not dynamically instantiated fragments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though I haven't found official documentation on this.

If you look at the code, all the lifecycle events for the fragments are invoked by the FragmentManager. For the support library, you can see that the FragmentActivity invokes dispatch*() on the FragmentManager during its lifecycle methods. The implementation of the dispatch*() method in FragmentManager invokes moveToState(int, int, int, boolean) which iterates through the active fragments and invokes moveToState(Fragment, int, int, int, boolean) on each. The non-support version does something similar.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java

So I think it's safe to assume that, when the activity is recreated, all the fragments that are being restored will have their lifecycle events invoked in order. And that the earlier lifecycle event (e.g. onCrate()) will be invoked for all fragments prior to a later lifecycle event (e.g. onStart()) for any fragment.

Answer (score 1):

The life cycle events of a fragment are independent and don't trigger events on other fragments.

Comment: Though the parent activity can trigger events on all of its children(in this case fragments)

Comment: I was more if the Android SDK waits for all events of the current state to be processed before triggering the next state on all fragment, rather than one fragment triggering other fragments. But I get your point that there is visibly no guarantee, also from: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html